# error in react " Attempted import error: 'TodoItem' is not exported from './Todoitem'. "

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have attached the code of both file

this is Todos.js
`

```
import React from 'react'
import {TodoItem} from "./Todoitem";
export const Todos = (props) => {
return (
    <div className="container">
        <h3 className="text-center my-5">Todos list</h3>
        {props.todos.map((todo)=>{
            return <TodoItem todo={todo} onDelete={props.onDelete}/>
        })}
    </div>
)}
```

`

it is Todoitem.js

`

```
import React from 'react';
export  const Todoitem = ({todo,  onDelete}) => {
return (
    <div>
        <h4 >{todo.title}</h4>
        <p  >{todo.description}</p>
        <button className= "btn btn-danger" onClick={onDelete}>Delete</button>    
    </div>
)}
```

`
please help

Comment: Can you please add some code like how you are importing Todoitem in Todos.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to update your Todos.js file to this

```
import React from 'react'
import {Todoitem} from "./Todoitem"; // Changed TodoItem to Todoitem
export const Todos = (props) => {
return (
    <div className="container">
        <h3 className="text-center my-5">Todos list</h3>
        {props.todos.map((todo)=>{
            return <TodoItem todo={todo} onDelete={props.onDelete}/>
        })}
    </div>
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you have named your export as `Todoitem` instead of `TodoItem`.

So, the following should work.

```js
import React from 'react'
import {TodoItem} from "./Todoitem";
export const Todos = (props) => {
return (
    <div className="container">
        <h3 className="text-center my-5">Todos list</h3>
        {props.todos.map((todo)=>{
            return <TodoItem todo={todo} onDelete={props.onDelete}/>
        })}
    </div>
)}

// TodoItem component
import React from 'react';
// you have named the below as Todoitem instead of TodoItem
export  const TodoItem = ({todo,  onDelete}) => {
return (
    <div>
        <h4 >{todo.title}</h4>
        <p  >{todo.description}</p>
        <button className= "btn btn-danger" onClick={onDelete}>Delete</button>    
    </div>
)}
```